# how to restrict user to create and edit accounting journal without posting the journal and also create another user to post journal in odoo 10

Tags: python-2.7, odoo-10

[Accounting Journal entries in odoo 10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cQqac.png)

i want the "Post" button shown under the edit button to disappear so that this current 'user' won't be able to post the journal entries, and i want another user to be able to post all the journal entries in odoo 10. pls share ur thought on how to go about it, And if there is any validation method that restrict users from posting journal entries, Your enlightenment will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please explain your needs. The question is confusing. If I understood your question correctly, you can use groups to the button. so those users in that group can visible the button

Comment: I want to create two users, one user will be able to post and the other won't be able to post from the journal entries.. Based on the image I uploaded.. How do I do dat from the group? Cos I tried using the group to disable to the post button but I was unable to that.. I   was just able restrict the user from writing, editing, deleting etc..

Comment: Create two groups(For posting and for creating). Add users to the group as your need, then write a security rule for POsting group(restrict create). Add groups to the post button